# Are keys in RDDs same as indexes in dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, key, rdd

in pyspark, key value pairs are used to define a RDD. But are they conceptually same as indexes in dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

RDDs in a more general way are a distributed collection of elements of data distributed across the cluster. Key/value pairs define a pair RDD, a type of RDD.

Spark Dataframes are inherently unordered so there is no concept of index like in pandas. Each row is treated as an independent collection of structured data.